# How do I profile XAML performance?

Tags: .net, performance, xaml

I'm getting deeper into xaml (WPF in my case), and really enjoying it.

However, I'd quite like to understand now (before it's too late) how to profile the performance of xaml. Are there any tools out there to do it, or is it a case of just learning it well and spotting potential performance problems by reading the code?

I've used various code profilers in the past, but don't recall one that can help profile a declarative language such as xaml.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [Performance Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc470664.aspx) tool in VS2010 to check performances of my WPF solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to profile a number of applications in the past that use WPF, but I have never used any tool that has any WPF-specific features.

I have used the VS2010 Performance Explorer and RedGate's ANTS profiler and they have always been sufficient to establish the bottlenecks, but then it's worth saying that those bottlenecks were **much** more common in my view model or data layer than in my view, and neither client (afaik) is able to easily point out performance issues within the XAML markup itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the XAML UI Responsiveness Tool (aka XAML Profiler). See [this talk](http://bit.ly/1ov59Mb) for reference.

Comment: Add details from the link and then put the link just as a reference when posting such solutions as answers..